# How to create a mini dump with more than Application data in it?

Tags: windows, debugging, crash-dumps

I have configured my WER to create a full memory mini dump:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps]
"DumpType"=dword:00000002
```

When I generate such a dump and open it in windbg it prints the following line:

> User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is
>   available

As you can see, not everything is included (like the handles are missing).

OK, so I have tried a custom dump type:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps]
"DumpType"=dword:00000000
"CustomDumpFlags"=dword:00000006
```

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it corresponds to `MiniDumpWithFullMemory|MiniDumpWithHandleData`, however, opening the new dump in windbg prints out the same line, no handle data.

So, my question is how can I configure my Windows 8 to automatically produce crash dumps with more than just the Application Data in it? For example, with the handles?

Comment: Looks okay.  Use Regedit.exe and make sure the keys are actually there and didn't end up in HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\etc instead.

Comment: They are there, alright.

Comment: A DumpType of 2 is a full memory dump. Did you actually try `!handle` and it failed?